# Canvas Zoom-in, Zoom-Out using mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm trying make my `<canvas>` zoomable (zoom-in, zoom-out).

I'm trying the following code to take care of the zooming functions, however, it does not work as expected because as soon as I try to zoom-in/out, the canvas goes empty/blank.

This leads me to believe the `mousewheel` function is working but something is off as it "deletes" the canvas drawing.

```
function drawZoom() {
var startScale = 1;
var scale = startScale;
var floor = $("#floorplan")[0].getContext("2d")
var width = floor.canvas.width;
var height = floor.canvas.height;
var intervalId;

var imageData = floor.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
var canvas = $("<canvas>").attr("width", width).attr("height", height)[0];
canvas.getContext("2d").putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

function drawContents(){
    var newWidth = width * scale;
    var newHeight = height * scale;

    floor.save();
    floor.translate(-((newWidth-width)/2), -((newHeight-height)/2));
    floor.scale(scale, scale);
    floor.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    floor.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
    floor.restore();
}

 $("#test").on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel',function(e) {

        var e =  e || window.event; // old IE support
        var theEvent = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || e.originalEvent.detail*-1;
        if(theEvent / 120 > 0) {
            zoomin();
        } else {
            zoomout();
        }
        if (e.preventDefault)
            e.preventDefault();
    });

    function zoomin()
    {
         scale = scale + 0.01;
         drawContents();
    }
    function zoomout()
    {
         scale = scale - 0.01;
         drawContents();
    }
}
```

[CodePen Live Example](https://codepen.io/izwicky/pen/xzKWYX)

What am I doing wrong here? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can add the wheel hanlder in your drawSettings like this:

```
//Drag settings start
        function drawSettings() {
           //snip....

            if (canvas.addEventListener) {
                // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
                canvas.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
                // Firefox
                canvas.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
            }
            // IE 6/7/8
            else canvas.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);
```

//the rest of your code...

The function to zoom in and out needs to be tailored for your example by using the value of delta. Add this function I found from here: https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/ and alter the canvas size as needed.

```
function MouseWheelHandler(e) {

            // cross-browser wheel delta
            var e = window.event || e; // old IE support
            var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail))); 

            canvas.style.width = Math.max(50, Math.min(800, canvas.width + (30 * delta))) + "px";
            canvas.style.height = Math.max(50, Math.min(800, canvas.width + (30 * delta))) + "px"; 
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: it does the resize function but the drawing still dissapears when zooming-in/out

Comment: You have to resize the image using the delta received from the wheel.

Comment: I solved the problem using my first code...turns out I didn't change a `var` name and it was messing everything